# charles proxy internet connection

Tags: charles-proxy

I am trying to collect log for Android mobile device through charles proxy. As soon as I connect my device charles proxy Application, I lose the internet connection on my mobile device and mac internet connection.

Steps followed:
1. Open charles proxy
2. Click on Proxy tab> Proxy settings
3. Made sure, port is 8888
4. Go to help (charles proxy app) and click on local IP
5. Connect the mobile device to same wifi
6. Long press on wifi and click on modify network
7. click on advance settings
8. choose proxy as "manual"
9. Enter proxy host name as "IP address from step 4 (local host ip address)"
10. Enter Proxy port as "8888"
11. Click on connect

**As soon as complete step 11, I lose my internet connection on the mobile device and mac. 
Though I can see the device's logs in charles proxy.**

If I open the browser it gives the below error:

On mobile device:
"This site cannot be reached.
www. google.com unexpectedly closed the connection"

on the web (mac machine) error message is:
"This site can’t be reached
www.google.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Note:
I have tried on windows 10 laptop too. Same issue. 
As soon as I close the charles proxy, the internet connection comes back.

Comment: Hi All, The issue was resolved for me.  For some reason for each site I visit, I had to individually enable SSL (though I have enabled SSL Proxy in Charles) and individually whitelist each website link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make sites whitelisted.
For this open menu:

1) Proxy->SSL Proxy Settings...

2) On SSL Proxy press "Add" button
[image: Charles Settings]

3) In Host add *

[image]

Done. This will allow any connections to any hosts.

Comment: For Chrome it is easy and I followed steps in http://www.ourpcgeek.com/configure-charles-for-chrome/ but it is not working for firefox/internet explorer

Comment: I had to uncheck the macOS Proxy option to make it work.
The option can be seen selected in the step 2 image of this answer.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: For me, With the above solution, I unchecked the mac OS proxy under tools did the trick.

Answer (score 17):

I selected "Tools" menu > "White List". Uncheck "Enable White List". This way all are whitelisted and not just the ones from Locations mentioned.

One more way would be to leave "Enable White List" checked, but Add an entry for both http and https protocols. Type * in host and save the changes. This way all locations will pass through.

Comment: Now renamed to Allow List

Comment: Now this is what I was looking for. So long been stuck in the loop of trying and retrying other solutions. THANKS!!

Answer (score 11):

By default, all hosts are whitelisted. If you whitelist one particuliar host (eg. right-click on it in the log and click "White List"), this default behaviour will not longer be applied and you will have to decide for each host whether you wish to whitelist them or not. A solution to your problem would be to go to the "Tools" menu > "White List" and change the "Blocking action" rule to something else than "Drop connection". [Charles Proxy White List Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ9jm.png)

Comment: Thanks! The whitelist option was flagged on for a fresh install for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the option *Allow list* isn't checked. From my understanding, Charles works by allowing lists only, which is why the browser doesn't work well.

Check screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 14:

1. After downloading profile from chls.pro/ssl and installing it from Settings -> General -> Profile.
2. Go to General -> about -> Certificate Trust Settings and allow Charles Proxy.
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Hey, this part really helped me ` Settings -> General -> Profil` I had no idea I had to do that from Charles website.

Comment: Thanks. Enable full trust did it for me. Needed a phone restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Windows + Ipad Air iOS 15 and Windows + Android 11. I did most of all thats whats written in SO. It started working after I unchecked brandmayer Windows in laptop settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).